# How to get rid of the dot after a chapter number?

Tags: chapters

I studied numerous questions and answers on the subject but I couldn't find a working solution.

```latex
\documentclass[10pt, a4paper] {report}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.25} 
\usepackage[dutch]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{palatino}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\section}
{\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\subsection}
{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\thesubsection}{1em}{}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{left=5cm, right=2.5cm, top=0.5cm, bottom=3cm, textheight=20cm}
\setlength {\parindent}{0pt}
\usepackage[document]{ragged2e}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\lfoot{Aanwijzingen vooraf}
\rfoot{\thepage}

\makeatletter
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
  \vspace*{50\p@}%
  {\parindent \z@ \raggedright \normalfont
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
      %\if@mainmatter
        %\LARGE\bfseries \@chapapp\space \thechapter
        \LARGE\bfseries \thechapter.\space%
        %\par\nobreak
        %\vskip 20\p@
      %\fi
    \fi
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \LARGE \bfseries #1\par\nobreak
    \vskip 40\p@
     }}
\makeatother
```

See the image for the present result.
[image: the present result]

Comment: Change `\thechapter.\space` to `\thechapter\space`

Comment: Thank you - so simple ... Do you also know how to enlarge the space between the number and the title?

Comment: I never noticed the dot. I found the answer to my second question myself.

Comment: Is it purposely that you chapter is numbered 0?